# C++ thread still `joinable()` after it finishes execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lifetime

I have the following function:

```
void threadProc(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "\n  thread #" << std::this_thread::get_id() << " says hi";
    }
    std::cout << "\n  Finished executing thread #" << std::this_thread::get_id();
}
```

And I am using it the following way:

```
int main(){
    try {
        std::thread t1(threadProc);
        t1.join();

        std::thread t2(threadProc);
        HANDLE handle = t2.native_handle(); 
        WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
        std::cout << "\n  thread t2 is joinable: " << std::boolalpha << t2.joinable() << "\n\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex){
        std::cout << "\n\n  " << ex.what() << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

> thread #21300 says hi
>
> thread #21300 says hi
>
> thread #21300 says hi
>
> thread #21300 says hi
>
> thread #21300 says hi
>
> Finished executing thread #21300
>
> thread #2136 says hi
>
> thread #2136 says hi
>
> thread #2136 says hi
>
> thread #2136 says hi
>
> thread #2136 says hi
>
> Finished executing thread #2136
>
> thread t2 is joinable: true

And then it crashes when the try block goes out of scope because `abort()` was called on `t2`.

My question is, why is `t2` still `joinable()` even when its `threadProc` was over? Why did it not finish processing?

Moreover, I am using `WaitForSingleObject` to ensure that I wait until `t2` finishes processing. I also added the 5 seconds wait to make sure it takes its time to finish its processing. Yet something is still not done.

I know I can use `t2.join()` or `t2.detach()` but why do I have to? `t2` has already finished processing (I think).

---

**EDIT**: I have tried the following code:

```
int main() {
    try {
        std::thread t1([]() {std::cout << "\n\n  Hi from thread #" << std::this_thread::get_id(); });
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "\n\n  " << ex.what() << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And still the thread is joinable. I looked up the `joinable` reference and they say:

> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.

So this isn't related to `WaitForSingleObject` anymore. The question is why a thread is still considered `joinable()` after it finished execution?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394123/stdthread-finishes-before-i-can-detach-it/31966972) which confused me even more as it states that when the thread finished execution it was not `joinable()` even before calling `join()` or `detach()`.

Comment: Mixing windows specific APIs `WaitForSingleObject ` with std c++ APIs does not seems good. Specifically the way in which handle is used.

Comment: @sameerkn edited..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The question is why a thread is still considered joinable() after it finished execution?

Because you might want to write code that join()s it.  If `t.joinable()` automatically became false upon termination, then there would be no safe way to call `t.join()`.  You could write this:

```
if (t.joinable()) {
    t.join();
}
```

But that still could throw an exception if the thread terminated after `t.joinable()` had returned `true`, but before the caller was able to complete the `t.join()` call.

Having the thread remain joinable until it actually is join()ed is simpler behavior to describe, and it's easier to write code that uses it correctly.

Answer (score 12):

`joinable` doesn't mean `still_running` , joinable simply means the thread object is not "empty" (as result of default construction or move) and is associated with a real OS-thread of execution.

if the thread is empty, that means there is nothing to join, hence, the thread is not "joinable".

if the thread is not empty, you can make the current thread wait for it, hence it is "joinable".

Comment: So it is up to the OS to determine whether it is joinable or not?

Comment: no. it is up to your code only. it's like the difference between an empty unique pointer and a non empty unique pointer. in the first case, the pointer doesn't point to an object. a joinable thread is a `std::thread` object which "points" to a real running thread. if the thread was default constructed or moved, the `std::thread` object does not point to a real running thread

Comment: Oh, I have tried doing this `std::thread *t = new std::thread(....)` in a loop and it didn't crash, not even once, and I didn't call `detach` nor `join`. Except of course when I called `delete t` it immediately crashed

Comment: that's because `std::thread*` is a C-Pointer and it will not try to delete the pointer it points to. try `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>` and see what happens.

Comment: Yup, `unique_ptr` also crashed. I got the point now. However, why does it happen sometimes that the thread is not joinable without detach/join is called? Who decided that?

Comment: @Everyone if the thread is default constructed or moved, it is not joinable anymore, since the "real" OS-thread it points either never created (you didn't supply any callable) or was moved to another thread object. ask yourself why `std::unique_ptr` is sometimes points to null, and sometimes not.

Comment: Yeah I know, but take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394123/stdthread-finishes-before-i-can-detach-it/31966972
it is NOT default constructed, nor moved, yet it is not joinable

Comment: it **IS** joinable before calling `detach`. `detach` makes it not joinable because `detach` empties the thread object.

Comment: detach can only be called on joinable objects, and there is a reason why it is recommended to check if joinable before detach/join. And I don't know what the reason is. If no copy/move construction was made, and no join/detach was made, then why should I check if it joinable to join it? It must be joinable by definition, yet in the question I linked, it wasn't, and he failed to call detach

Comment: moreover, I know what detach means, it separates the execution line from the object, so the thread can be emptied without worrying about the execution line.

Comment: Its an `invalid_argument` if `joinable()` is false when `join()` is called.   `std::thread helper;    helper.join();` this will throw exception. Since `helper` is empty or in a simply saying: does not contribute to any execution.

Comment: Sometimes it helps the noob to understand if you explain the difference between a thread and a thread _object_.  Often they do not realize that those are different things.

Comment: @jameslarge The "noob" knows the difference. The "noob" does not understand why sometimes `joinable` is `false` on a thread object even without calling `detach`/`join`, and there was no copy/move construction done on the thread object. And so far no one explained it. So do the noob a favor and explain :)

Comment: @Everyone, There's a lot of questions about threading on this site that are asked by people who have a vague idea of what threads actually are.  I apologize if I mistook you for one of those.  Meanwhile, I'm reluctant to offer an answer of my own because I'm a rank C++ noob, coming from Java and still struggling to learn the C++ way.

Comment: @jameslarge I have worked extensively with `Threads` in C# and created my own blocking queue for locking and thread safety stuff. I know what should be done. All I am asking is why sometimes in C++ a thread object becomes not `joinable` even though it wasn't touched.

Comment: It doesn't. If a thread object is joinable, the only ways it can become non-joinable (assuming nothing else in your code triggers undefined behaviour) are to move from it, assign to it, or explicitly call join() or detach(). If something gave you the idea that a thread could spontaneously become non-joinable, either your source was mistaken or you misinterpreted it.

Comment: @RossSmith this is what confused me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394123/stdthread-finishes-before-i-can-detach-it/31966972